# How to deserialize boolean to string

Tags: spring, serialization, spring-boot

I have a property like this:

```
    @CatalogExportField(columnName = "K", headerName = "catalog name")
private Boolean mpAvailable;
```

I need to get this as string while parsing in other class

```
   private CatalogExportDto convert(Variant variant, boolean willHaveProductTypeFields) {
    CatalogExportDto dto = new CatalogExportDto()


        .setMpAvailable(variant.isMpAvailable())
```

But here it is boolean.

I need to do somethng like this i think.

```
    @JsonDeserialize(using = BooleanDeserializer.class)
@JsonProperty("Timestamp")
ZonedDateTime timestamp;
@CatalogExportField(columnName = "K", headerName = "catalog nae")
private Boolean mpAvailable;
```

And another class like this

```
public class BooleanDeserializer {
@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
```

but could not find any proper example.

this is also

```
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface CatalogExportField {

    String color() default "#56aaff";

    String columnName() default "";

    String headerName() default "";

    String displayName() default "";
}
```

Comment: What is `@CatalogExportField`, How it implemented?

Comment: @DoNhuVy added it

Answer (score 1):

You can use jackson, it deserealize you're booleans automatically, there are a lot of examples in StackOverflow:

[Jackson renames primitive boolean field by removing 'is'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32270422/jackson-renames-primitive-boolean-field-by-removing-is)

[Fasterxml Jackson automatically converts non-boolean value to a boolean value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40244770/fasterxml-jackson-automatically-converts-non-boolean-value-to-a-boolean-value)

And you always can do your custom, of course:

https://hussainpithawala.wordpress.com/2011/05/11/overriding-default-serializationdeserialization-behaviour-of-jackson-json-serializer/