# In JSON boolean type allow to pass int, instead of throwing error

Tags: json, rest, jackson, jax-rs

Here,

> `isChecked` and 
>   `isPrime` both are the boolean type. If I am passing integer to both value, in my java code instead of throwing exception/error (code should expect either 'true' or 'false'), it is mapping with `true` value in my POJO class. I am assuming that it because of any number greater than 0 will take boolean true. To avoid this thing, any suggestions? I am using jax-rs for deserializing and serialize to java object.

```
@JsonProperty
private boolean isChecked;
```

(In setter method, it set with `true` value)

Comment: Just to clarify your question, currently Jackson allows numbers for booleans, and you want an exception to be thrown instead if there is a number?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/40244770/2587435

Comment: @PaulSamsotha Yes, I want an exception. Thank you for your inputs and provide me the useful link. If you have any other things, I would appreciate if you can share here. Thanks again.